# Stationary time series input to ARMA-GARCH

Tags: arima, stationarity, garch

I’m thoroughly confused as I have been using ARMA-GARCH to model a conditional mean and conditional variance so I can effectively remove them by taking the residuals and be left with an i.i.d process.

I have read however that the input to an ARMA model must be stationary. My question therefore is how can a stationary process contain both conditional mean and conditional variance?

Although I’m starting to also think I’m misunderstanding ARMA completely as the outputs of ARMA look stationary. If I take the residuals of an ARMA model what have I potentially removed from the model?

Comment: I suggest you to look into the definition of stationarity. A stationary process is not prohibited from having a time-varying conditional mean and/or conditional variance.

Comment: This is where my confusion occurs:

In mathematics and statistics, a stationary process (a.k.a. a strict/strictly stationary process or strong/strongly stationary process) is a stochastic process whose unconditional joint probability distribution does not change when shifted in time.[1] Consequently, parameters such as mean and variance also do not change over time.

Comment: does it mean marginal mean and variance have to be constant, and if that is the case are we removing conditional mean and variance using ARMA-GARCH?

Comment: Your answer contains the relevant point: **unconditional** distribution. Meanwhile, conditional distribution can be time varying.